# How to prevent using function calls in Angular template expressions

Tags: angular, typescript, performance

I have a child component that gets a year list from parent, and needs to style an element if that list contains the current year.

**The child ts**:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() listYears: Array<number> = [];
  year = 2022;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  existInList() {
    return this.listYears.find(x => x === this.year);
  }

}
```

**the child html:**

```
<div [style.background-color]="existInList() ? 'red' :  'blue' ">
  </div>
```

**and the parent html:**

```
<app-child [listYears]="[2022]"></app-child>
```

Because the condition for the style uses a method, and the recommendation is to prevent using function calls in Angular template expressions ([never use function calls in Angular template](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496))
so how can I achive this without a function call?

I assume that inserting the condition within the template instead of in ts, like this:

```
<div [style.background-color]="listYears.find(x => x === year) ? 'red' :  'blue' ">
  </div>
```

does not matter for performance.
Am I wrong? If not - what's the write way?

Thanks

Comment: go with `ngClass`, this way you don't mix style in html

Comment: NgClass won't help here, the problem is the function call from template. This is unrecommende practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is, of course, to use an Angular `Pipe`.
[Here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) is a link to docs.

Pipes are maintained exactly for this, to transform data on template in a smart and performance considered way.

Your `pipe` will look like this:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'existInList'
})
export class ExistInListPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(listYears: number[], year: number): string {
        return listYears.find((x) => x === year) ? 'red' :  'blue';
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div [style.background-color]="listYears | existInList : year">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It helped me. but can you let me know why you choose the **pipe** and not the **directive** ?

Comment: @user3345721 The difference between a Pipe and a Directive in one word is: A pipe transformas the data, a Directive manipulate the Html element.
So then, you are actually right, since you wanted to convert the div background color you could use a directive as well.
The reason I first thought on a pipe was because your case was a very simple change, which based just on data which is alrady available on your component without many calculations. That's why a pipe is good enugh I think. But again, you're right that in the basic concept a directive is the right solution for manipulating elements

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a setter method along with HostBinding.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  private _listYears: number[];
  yearToStyle: number = 2022;

  @HostBinding('style.color')
  background: string;

  @Input()
  set listYears(value: number[]) {
    this._listYears = value;

    this.background = value.includes(this.yearToStyle) ? 'red' : 'blue';
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4hgtdn?file=src/app/hello.component.ts